# Can I make 3D Games with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, 3d

Is it possible to make native 3D games (like cs:go, call of duty, battlefield, etc) with Javascript?
I want to create a game that will not be played in web browser, but be installed and played on user machine like every game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use Babylon.js.

I've found some free tutorials in youtube and I think I can use Electron.js to run as a native desktop game

Answer (score 2):

You can check [three.js](https://threejs.org/), which is a Javascript library that helps you to build 3D Games. Although it doesn't quite fulfill your condition, as it also runs on a web browser.

I am not quite sure about building native games with javascript, but you can use [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org/) to make a desktop application of your javascript game.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Unity 3D.

Learning is very intuitive.

With a single code you can run on Browser, Mobile, PC and if you can get a development kit even on Game Consoles.

Look at some simple examples in browsers:

- http://cycleblob.com/
- https://akirodic.com/p/jellyfish/
- https://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_pasta.html

Now a list of great games made with Unity:

- https://sundaysundae.co/best-games-made-with-unity/

And to conclude, the framework is free, and it has a website for several free and paid assets:

- https://assetstore.unity.com/top-assets/top-free

Here a course Unit with JS (I think it is mostly used in C, but it works perfectly in JS):

- https://www.udemy.com/course/unity-com-javascript/

I hope I have helped, and may this motivate you!